# Magento save only 325 attribute values

Tags: php, apache, magento, suhosin

admin use magento administration for administrate attribute sets and their values.  Our shop have more than 325 values in one or more attribute sets, but magento save only 325 values. Why? We use suhosin with this setting:

```
# own setting for suhosin                                                   
php_value suhosin.mail.protect 0                                            
php_value suhosin.memory_limit 512M                                         
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 18000                                       
php_value suhosin.post.max_value_length 500000                              
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 18000                                    
php_value suhosin.request.max_value_length 500000                           

# default setting for suhosin                                               
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
```

Our memory limit and vars limit not fully used. It's only our problem? Can anybody help me, please? Ths ;)

Answer (score 0):

Suhosin logs all violations if logging is switched on, e.g.

```
suhosin.log.sapi = 511
```

Log messages should appear in the normal PHP or Apache logfile. For more logging options, please refer to http://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html